# Help to understand limits in multivariable calculus

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, book-recommendation

Can someone show me some examples of limits by definition $\epsilon - \delta $ in multivariable calculus? I tried to understand in the books, but I´m quite confused right now.

Pd: If you know about a good book for this please tell me, I´m tryly confused.

Comment: It is the same as the single variable case except that in the expression $|x-c|\lt\delta$ the absolute value means the distance between $x$ and $c$ because they are vectors, not real numbers.

Comment: What book did you try?

Comment: I tried with Advanced Calculus by Watson Fulks and Multivariable Calculus by Dennis G Zill

Comment: The standard (Euclidean) norm on $\Bbb R^n$ defined by $||x||:=\left(\sum\limits_1^n x_i^2\right)^{1/2}$ naturally induces a metric $d(x,y)=||x-y||$ on $\Bbb R^n$ making it a complete metric space $(\Bbb R^n,d)$, so you can now do analysis on $\Bbb R^n$ with the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition replacing absolute values for the single variable case with the metric $d$ of $\Bbb R^n$. Notice that for the single variable case, i.e., $\Bbb R$, the metric $d$ reduces to the absolute value function.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$f(x,y)= 3x+2y$$

Prove $$ lim_{(x,y)\to (1,5)}  f(x,y)= 13 $$

Let $\epsilon >0 $ be given.

We need to fine a $\delta >0$ such that if $$\sqrt {(x-1)^2 + (y-5)^2 }< \delta $$

Then $$ | 3x+2y -13| < \epsilon $$

$$ | 3x+2y -13|= |(3x -3) +(2y -10)| \le 3|x-1| + 2|y-5|$$

Thus if $$|x-1|< \epsilon /6$$ and $$|y-5|< \epsilon /4$$

We get $$ | 3x+2y -13|< \epsilon $$

We know that we can make $$|x-1|< \epsilon /6$$ and $$|y-5|< \epsilon /4$$

Let $$ \delta = \epsilon /6 $$

If  $$\sqrt {(x-1)^2 + (y-5)^2 }< \delta $$ Then we have $$|x-1|< \epsilon /6$$ and $$|y-5|< \epsilon /4$$

Thus $$ | 3x+2y -13| < \epsilon $$

And the proof is complete.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any books to recommend.

Instead, here an example.

> $1$) Prove the following limit
>   \begin{align}
> \lim_{(x, y)\rightarrow (0, 0)}\frac{xy\log(1+x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2} = 0
> \end{align}

**Pre-Proof/ Scratch Work**: Observe we have that
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{xy\log(1+x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}-0 \right| \le \frac{\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)\log(1+x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{1}{2}\log(1+x^2+y^2).
\end{align}
Next, note that
\begin{align}
\log(1+t) \leq t \ \ \text{ whenever } \ \ t\geq 0
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\left| \frac{xy\log(1+x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2).
\end{align}
With this, we are ready to write down our $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof.

**Proof**: Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $\delta = \sqrt{2\varepsilon}$. Then we see that 
\begin{align}
\left| \frac{xy\log(1+x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}\right| \leq \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2) < \frac{1}{2}\delta^2 = \varepsilon
\end{align}
whenever $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$. $\square$

Here's another example (slightly more complicated):

> $2$) Prove the following limit
>   \begin{align}
> \lim_{(x, y)\rightarrow (1, 2)} \frac{xy}{1+x^2+y^2} =\frac{1}{3}
> \end{align}

**Pre-Proof/ Scratch Work**: Observe we have that
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{xy}{1+x^2+y^2}-\frac{1}{3} \right| =&\  \left|\frac{3xy-(1+x^2+y^2)}{3(1+x^2+y^2)}\right| = \frac{|3xy-1-x^2-y^2+2x-2x+4y-4y|}{3(1+x^2+y^2)}\\
=&\ \frac{|3(x-1)(y-2)-(x-1)^2-(y-2)^2+4(x-1)-(y-2)|}{3(1+x^2+y^2)}\\
\leq&\ \frac{1}{3}\left( 3|x-1||y-2|+|x-1|^2+|y-2|^2+4|x-1|+|y-2|\right)\\
\leq&\ \frac{1}{3}\left(|x-1|(3|y-2|+|x-1|+4)+|y-2|(|y-2|+1)\right)\\
\leq&\ \frac{1}{3}(|x-1|+|y-2|)(4|y-2|+4|x-1|+5)\\
\leq&\ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}\left(4\sqrt{2}\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}+5 \right)\\
\leq&\ \frac{8}{3}\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}\left(\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}+2 \right).
\end{align}

**Proof:** Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and choose $\delta = \sqrt{\frac{3}{8}}(\sqrt{\varepsilon+1}-1)$. Then we see that
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{xy}{1+x^2+y^2}-\frac{1}{3} \right| \leq \frac{8}{3}\delta(\delta+2)<\varepsilon
\end{align}
whenever $\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}<\delta$. $\square$